# Is there a design pattern used in Fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm wondering what's the name (if it exists), of the design pattern used in Fancybox.

From my understanding, you set a number of parameters (title, description, buttonContent, etc), and create a type of fancybox, for example a yes/no fancybox.

When you do this, fancybox expects that you implement the methods to be called onYesClick, onNoclick.... what is this called?

I looked around the website & documentation, and couldnt find the answer.

Thanks a lot

Comment: callbacks? i'm not sure if this is really a design pattern. you're just passing an object, into a function. the object contains properties, some of said properties may contain either function references or anonymous functions that will get called at a later time.

Comment: @KevinB I understand the concept of callback, i was refering to having some kind of 'contract', that you need to specify this this & this, or it wont work

Comment: I wonder what is the nature of your question : are you documenting something or writing a tutorial or something like that? could you describe a specific scenario when creating this "type" of fancybox (a code example) and ask then about what part of your code you need to know "how it is called".

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be called "Object Literal pattern". See this blog post about organizing the code - http://rmurphey.com/blog/2009/10/15/using-objects-to-organize-your-code/